# It shows when i go to update / install apps

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

[image: Ubuntu install/update problem screenshot]

I am try to solve this problem to watching youtube video.but i cannot solved it.now i looking for help.please if anyone understand my problem .please tell how to fix it?

I cannot update /install any kind of software in my machine.so,please tell how to fixed the problem